# how do image alignment using opencv orb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have two images  one is input images and other one is template image . For image alignment I am using ORB and homography matrix. But output images are not showing in a perfect way .
My code is

```
 def get(img1,img2):
   # Convert to grayscale. 
   img1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
   img2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
   height, width = img2.shape 

   # Create ORB detector with 5000 features. 
   orb_detector = cv2.ORB_create(1000) 
 
   # Find keypoints and descriptors. 
   # The first arg is the image, second arg is the mask 
   # (which is not reqiured in this case). 
   kp1, d1 = orb_detector.detectAndCompute(img1, None) 
   kp2, d2 = orb_detector.detectAndCompute(img2, None) 

   # Match features between the two images. 
  # We create a Brute Force matcher with 
   # Hamming distance as measurement mode. 
   matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck = True) 

   # Match the two sets of descriptors. 
   matches = matcher.match(d1, d2) 

   # Sort matches on the basis of their Hamming distance. 
   matches.sort(key = lambda x: x.distance) 
   #     print(len(matches))
   # Take the top 90 % matches forward. 
   matches = matches[:int(len(matches)*90)] 
   no_of_matches = len(matches) 


   # Define empty matrices of shape no_of_matches * 2. 
   p1 = np.zeros((no_of_matches, 2)) 
   p2 = np.zeros((no_of_matches, 2)) 

   for i in range(len(matches)): 
       p1[i, :] = kp1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt 
       p2[i, :] = kp2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt 

   # Find the homography matrix. 
   homography, mask = cv2.findHomography(p1, p2, cv2.RANSAC) 

   # Use this matrix to transform the 
   # colored image wrt the reference image. 
   transformed_img = cv2.warpPerspective(img1, 
                                        homography, (width, height)) 

   # Save the output.
   #     cv2.imwrite(r"output.jpg", transformed_img)
   return transformed_img

if __name__ == "__main__":

   img1_color = cv2.imread(r"1.jpg") # Image to be aligned. 
   img2_color = cv2.imread(r"reference.jpg") # Reference image.
   image_transform=get(img1_color, img2_color)

   plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
   plt.imshow(image_transform)
```

When I use the same documents that means one template(reference image) and other is input image(any skew image).That code work better . But when I take a different images which is not same as document . that mean there are some different thing in this type of images. And run the code it does not give the good result . My problem is that For the different images what shold I do so that my images perfectly aligned to the template images?

Comment: `matches = matches[:int(len(matches)*90)]` makes no sense. Did you mean `matches = matches[:90] `?

Comment: Also, why would these images be perfectly aligned? This isn't a picture of the same page

Comment: okay I see and inform if any error occure with the same images

Comment: If the template and input images are not same that means previous images for tthat condition what should be done . please tell me if any post are there related to this

Comment: If I use the blank template (target image).For this condition what will I do to align the images in this code ?

Comment: I am unable to answer your question. Please rigorously define an input and an output and explain why what you want doesn't work. This is harder for images, but it is nessecary. read [mre]

Comment: Voted to close this as this is not a [mre]. Clearly define what you input and what you expect as output. No one will do that for you.

Comment: I want to ask only If the page of the images are not same then what should I do for that condition ?

Comment: This is up to you to define. What do you *want* to do in that case?

Comment: For that cases I used the canny edge detection method and four_point_transform function (getperspectivetransform). They gives better result for some images. but Some image are shown as blank . .how get the better result any idea please tell

Comment: Please ask a new question for this.

Comment: okay , I ask a new question for that cases